# Index on ORDER BY after JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

Are there any cases where index on order by clause is used after join?

And when does order by operation proceed before join?

Is there a salient example where index is used after `join` in a query (that has no sub-queries)?

For example, this query:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.b = t2.b order by t2.c
```

Where `t1` length is more than `t2`'s. It will join t1 to t2. The index `t1.b` is used for the join. Then we can make index on `c` column for `order by` on the `t2` table. However, this is not the behavior I see in MySQL.

Comment: You can't order something that you don't have. You can't have the data before you perform a JOIN, since a JOIN affects what data you get back. Now, the problem with your question is that there could be subqueries, which in turn are able to use their own `order by` clauses and what not. The issue of whether an index is used or not is completely irrelevant. What indexes do is helping database do less work. So if it could be used before or after join, why would that matter for you? If you have an actual problem, post that instead of "what if" scenario.

Comment: Ok, can you give an example where index is used after join in query without subqueries? For example, this query: `code` SELECT * FROM t1 join t2 ON t1.b = t2.b order by t2.c `code` and t1 size more than t2. It will join t2 to t1. We have index t1(b) for join. And we can make index on c column for order by on t2 table, but mysql don't use it.

Comment: MySQL won't use indexes if their cardinality is too low. What that means is that MySQL will determine it will do the job quicker without index. Basically, what you're worried about is MySQL not using an index - that's quite normal for low row counts and indexes with low cardinality. Nothing to worry about really. However, without further info -  table schema, execution plan - all that's left is to speculate.